# Projective General Linear Group in GAP

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, gap

I know that in the GAP system the command $PGL(d,q)$ gives the projective general linear group of $d \times d$ matrices over the finite field with $q$ elements, But what if I need $PGL(d,F)$ where elements of matrices belong to a number field $F$. I could not find anything on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a predefined way of representing $PGL(d,F)$ for $F$ being a number field. Beyond the quetion of how to represent elements (GAP does not have permutations of infinite domains),there are questions of finite generation or testing membership in subgroups, for neither of which I am aware of any algorithm.